# How do I get the _version attribute in python-eve?

Tags: python, eve

I'm using [python-eve](http://python-eve.org/) to build a restfull API and using the global settings `VERSIONING=True` to version my schemas. This gives me a new attribute in my schemas called `_version` but I can't get it like a normal attribute.

E.g.: `data.name`

How do I get the `_version` attribute? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`_version` is relative to the document. It is not available for the single field, if that's what you are asking for.